# change to date formatting.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is change normal number formatting to date formatting in here (http://jsfiddle.net/prL83/)?

typed date from right to left `dir="rtl"` in this format, `YYYY/MM/DD`.

1. first typed the day(`DD`)
2. secend typed the month(`MM`)
3. thrid typed the year(`YYYY`)

   $('.find_input').delegate("input.numeric:text", 'keyup', function () {
           $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
           $(this).val($val)
       });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
$dateSet = 0;
$monthSet = 0;
$yearSet = 0;

$('.find_input').delegate("input.numeric:text", 'keyup', function () {
    $val = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, "").match(/\d{1,12}$/);
    if($val == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        $val = $val.join("");
    }

    if($(this).val().match(/\d{4,}$/) && $val.length%2 == 0) {
        $val = $val.match(/\d{2}/g);
        if($yearSet < $monthSet) {
            if($val.length == 4) {
                $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/,'$3/$1/$2'));
                $yearSet++;
            } else if($val.length == 6){

                $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/,'$4/$2/$3'));
                $yearSet++;
            }
        } else {
            if($monthSet < $dateSet) {
                $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,'$1/$4/$3'));
                $monthSet++;
            } else {

                if($val.length == 2) {
                       $(this).val($val.reverse().join("/"));
                    $dateSet++;
                    $monthSet++;
                } else {
                       $(this).val($val.join("").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,'$1/$2/$4'));
                    $dateSet++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In this sample you, adding slash after end typed like:` 00000000 =after end typed=> 0000/00/00`. did can adding slash during typing, not adding slash after end typed value eight?

Comment: this changed not was my mean, i not want adding slash `/` after end typed value eight. i want adding slash `during typing`(when typing, no in end type). this is your sample: http://jsfiddle.net/prL83/41/